# HERE Style Editor - Adjust Attribute Min-Zoom

Tags: heremaps

In HERE's style editor, one can select the gear icon underneath the zoom controls to view the map settings. From there, data properties can be toggled on, and various features of a data point can be seen--such as a road's minimum zoom level.

Those data settings can only be viewed in that window, so I was wondering if there is a way to edit them--specifically the minimum zoom level; as I would like to have the minor roads and road labels render at a lower zoom.

I can, of course, adjust the line widths of roads at various zoom levels, but it has no effect prior to the roads' minimum zoom levels. I tried looking at all the options in the editor, but haven't found any way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say, if you want to show the minor category of streets at global zoom levels, for example 4 or 5. That's not possible. The visualization also depends on the data stored at a particular level of details. At global levels, some minor streets are not stored in the data at all. The web rendering engine is configured to only fetch certain level of details of data in order to avoid pulling too many tiles, which would kill the rendering performance.